# How using Vim alphabetically sort JS es6 imports

Tags: vim, eslint, tslint

I use `vim` as `IDE` for `typescript` project.

```
import { FlightInfo } from './FlightInfo'                                                                               
import { InfoBlockProps, InfoRowProps, INavigationFlightOfferDataProps } from './interfaces'                            
import { getDiscountData, formatDataByServicesType, selectAdministrationFee } from './functions'
```

Also, I use `ts-lint` rule for check sorting:

```
 ...
 ordered-imports": [                                                                                                
      true,                                                                                                             
      {                                                                                                                 
        "import-sources-order": "lowercase-first",                                                                      
        "named-imports-order": "lowercase-first"                                                                        
      }                                                                                                                 
    ],
 ...
```

And get errors:

```
ERROR: 11:1   ordered-imports  Import sources within a group must be alphabetized.
ERROR: 11:10  ordered-imports  Named imports must be alphabetized.
ERROR: 12:1   ordered-imports  Import sources within a group must be alphabetized.
ERROR: 12:10  ordered-imports  Named imports must be alphabetized.
```

I am searching for a solution or plugin for fix this sorting errors.

Comment: what exactly should be sorted and how? have a look at `:h sort`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this situation, for me very well works `ts-lint --fix -c ./ts-congig.json my-file.ts` command.